# IntelliJ using the apache2 php interpreter?

Tags: php, apache, intellij-idea, phpstorm

I am using Ubuntu 14.04

I was reading this: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Installing+and+Configuring+XAMPP+with+PhpStorm+IDE#InstallingandConfiguringXAMPPwithPhpStormIDE-IntegratingthePHPexecutable

Problem is: there is no php executable for Apache. I think it just uses 
something like `/usr/bin/php -c /etc/php5/apache2` but this does not get accepted by IntelliJ.

[image]

without the `-c` command line option it works.

But it reads the wrong `php.ini` file (not the Apache one)

[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: youve most likley (unless youve changed it) got the same interpreter for cli and apache, so itll still point to the right place.  Its looking for a file path, not a command.

Comment: hmm yes the php executable is correct, the configuration file is wrong though

Comment: nothing i should worry about then?

Comment: Config is not wrong -- on your Linux distro PHP uses one config for CLI environment and another config when used by actual Apache. When you setting up "PHP Interpreter" it is used in CLI environment so info on 2nd screen is correct. Why do you need Apache one?

Comment: 2nd screen is correct.

Comment: @Toskan not at all